# Counter-example to G&P exercise

Tags: differential-topology

[Local diffeomorphism is diffeomorphism provided one-to-one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434187/local-diffeomorphism-is-diffeomorphism-provided-one-to-one)

Isn't this false, though? For instance, consider the map of $(0,1)\to S$ where $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set indicated by the black line in the picture

[image]

Follow up: Is this *not* a counter example for the reason that $S$ itself is not a manifold, and hence the exercise does not apply to the map $(0,1)\to S$?

Comment: Yes, that's right; $S$ isn't a manifold so the exercise doesn't apply.