# local diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$ and on manifolds.

Tags: differential-topology

I find the proof of diffoemorphism in Guillemin & Pallock's *Differential Topology* 1.3.3 is more or less independent of the fact that the manifold happen to be $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore are the same.

Then I am asking if my two proofs (primarily the latter one) are correct.

> GP 1.3.3: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a local diffeomorphism. Prove that the image of $f$ is an open interval and that, in fact $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ diffeomorphically onto this interval.

Proof: Since local diffeomorphism implies $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are globally smooth, it suffices to show that the local diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R} \to$ image$f$ is a bijection.  We know it's surjective since we restricted to its image. But if it is not surjective, by mean value theorem, there is some point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) = 0$.   However, the pushforward $df_{U_x}$ at $x$ must be a linear isomorphism.  This is a contradiction.

And right after:

> GP 1.3.5:
>   Prove that a local diffeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is actually a diffeomorphism of $X$ onto an open subset of $Y$, provided that $f$ is one-to-one.

Proof: Since local diffeomorphism implies $f$ are globally smooth and $f^{-1}$ are globally smooth within the image of $f$, it suffices to show that the local diffeomorphism $f: X \to$ image$f \subseteq Y$ is a bijection. We know it's surjective since we restricted to its image. Given $f$ is one-to-one, it is bijective. Hence a diffeomorphism onto an open subset of $Y$.

Comment: What is *GP*? Here and elsewhere you seem to be quoting from somewhere, but never bothered to tell us where form, afaics?

Comment: Notice that here you did not ask anything...

Comment: It is Guillemin & Pallock's _Differential Topology_

Comment: Like I said, I did not know that the fact I used in 1.3.3 was stated as a problem in 1.3.5, but your proof of 1.3.5 is problematic.

Comment: Oh @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez , I mean, it two problems on the textbook are identical to my eyes, then probably I am wrong somewhere. So I am asking for the distinction - and if I understand the distinction correctly, that 1.3.5 is just an extension of 1.3.3 from $\mathbb{R}$ to a general manifold, then I am asking if my two proofs (primarily the latter on) are correct.

Comment: Oh @Ink... Could you tell me where went wrong..

Comment: Please add all the relevant information and the actual question to the body of the question itself. In particular, I do not see where you aked a question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez ok, added.

Comment: I think the idea is that the $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ case is easily visualisable, so you first get an easy one to warm up. Then you get the general one, to see what parts you actually _needed_, and which special properties of $\mathbb{R}$ that you may have used for the first were actually irrelevant.

Comment: @WishingFish why local diffeomorphism implies inverse f is  globally smooth ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your first proof is this:

> > 1. Why is $f$ an ***open map***?
> > 2. Why is the image an interval?
> > 3. Also tautologically $f$ is surjective onto its image so what's going on with the MVT in 1.3.3?

Well the first actually this follows immediately from $f$ being a local diffeomorphism! For any $f(y) \in f(\Bbb{R})$, $f$ a local diffeomorphism implies there is $U$ open about $y$ such that $f(U)$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$ about $f(y)$. Necessarily $f(U) \subseteq f(\Bbb{R})$ and so immediately this means $f(\Bbb{R})$ is open. For 2) the image is an interval because $f(\Bbb{R})$ is an open connected set which is an interval from basic real analysis.  To complete the problem, you just need to tell us why $f$ is injective: If $x,y$ with $x\neq y$ are such that $f(x) = f(y)$, the MVT implies there is $d$ between $x$ and $y$ so that $f'(d) = 0$. Now how does this contradict what we have?

> > **Exercise:** Complete the proof above for why $f$ has to be injective with the following hints:
> >
> > 1. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. For any $U \subseteq M$ open and $p\in M$, $T_pM \cong T_pU$.
> > 2. A functor always takes isomorphisms to isomorphisms. If $f'(d) = 0$ then the induced map on tangent spaces at $d$ is the (.....) map.

Comment: I think, there is a mistype in the problem: The sentence starting by "But if it is not surjective" should rather be "But if it is not bijective"..

Comment: 2. A functor always takes isomorphisms to isomorphisms. If $f'(d) = 0$ then the induced map on tangent spaces at $d$ is the (identity) map?

Comment: However, for 1, I don't really know how to prove. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: @WishingFish I just proved 1 for you. If $f'(d) = 0$, then this means that $f'$ is the zero map!

Comment: OH, I mean 1 in the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

We know local diffeomorphisms are open maps. Let $N = f(X)$. By assumption we have a bijective local diffeomorphism $f: X \to N$.   To prove that $f$ is smooth let $x \in X$.   There exists an open set $U \subseteq X$ around $x$ such that $f_U : U \to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.  Hence, there exists charts $(U_x, \phi)$ $(U_{f(x)}, \psi)$ of $x$ and $f(x)$ such that $f(U_x) \subseteq f(U_{f(x)})$ and

$$\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(U_x) \to \psi(U_{f(x)})$$

is smooth as a map between Euclidean space.  Hence, $f$ is smooth.  For any $f(x) \in N$, the map $f_U^{-1} : f(U) \to U$ is a diffeomorphism, so the exact same argument shows that $f^{-1}$ is smooth.  I think this proves 1.3.5.

Comment: okay, now I see why these two questions are different. :-P

Comment: How about surjectivity? Is that for free when we restrict the image of $f$ to $f(N)$?

Comment: Hello Ink - and why $$\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(U_x) \to \psi(U_{f(x)})$$ is smooth as a map between Euclidean space, then $f$ is smooth...? Thank you~~~ -)

Comment: Is that because locally, $\psi, f, \phi$ are all smooth, and the composition carry any point in $\mathbb{R}^m$ smoothly to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $f$ is globally smooth? Feel I lost something here..

Comment: A new question is posted here demonstrates the recent progress - thanks in advance! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434187/local-diffeomorphism-is-diffeomorphism-provided-one-to-one

Comment: @WishingFish Look up the definition of a smooth map (between manifolds).

Comment: hmm. it asks from $X \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: @WishingFish There should be a proper definition on Wikipedia.

Comment: AHA! Find the right one! Thank you so much Ink!!

Comment: Sorry for bombing you with the questions - but is the surjectivity part looks correct to you?

Comment: @WishingFish Yes

Comment: Thank you Ink. I reconstructed your proof for the smoothness of $f^{-1}$, would you please take a look at it if you can spare some time? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434187/local-diffeomorphism-is-diffeomorphism-provided-one-to-one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can get 1.3.3, by applying the more general 1.3.5, $\ $ *and* $\ $ the additional fact for $\Bbb R$ that each local homeomorphism $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is *injective* (that you showed by the mean value theorem).